# "Cross origin are only supported for HTTP" and "DOMException.NETWORK_ERR 19"

Tags: html, xml, ajax, http

I have written the below Ajax file which will request for authanticate.xml file to authenticate.

```
  var file_path = "var file_path = "C:/Users/sankett/Desktop/authanticate.xml";   
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {

    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("person");

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      if(document.getElementById("pswd").value == x[i].childNodes[1].nodeValue){
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="AUTHENTICATED";
      }
      else{
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="ACCESS DENIED";
       }
      }
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET",file_path,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

But browser is showing me XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/sankett/Desktop/authanticate.xml. `Cross origin are only supported for HTTP` and `DOMException.NETWORK_ERR 19` am I missing something?

Below is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authenticate>
   <person category="Admin">
      <username>Sanket</username>
      <password>laurentiis</password>
   </person>
</authenticate>
```

Comment: authanticate.xml is in the same folder where my ajax file is.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browser you're using, it might be an expected behaviour. Pretty much all browsers, given a local file path, try to open the file via `file://` protocol. I know that WebKit treats the `file://` protocol as unsafe (i.e. you can't make the AJAX requests to this protocol regardless of where the file actually is). Gecko allowed you for subdirectories last time I checked and I'm not sure about IE

The best solution would be to access the files via `http://localhost` instead, as behaviour of HTTP protocol is much more reliable. Both in your JS code and when you open the page in the browser.